# Why doesn't this userscript work on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, userscripts

I was writing user script for Google Chrome that would automatically open a specific chat tab, but it's not working,

I think that it is because the `Chat.openTab` is not specifically defined, because when i run the code in the javascript console it works fine.

CODE:

```
var face = "facebook.com"
var domain = document.domain
if (domain = face)
{
 Chat.openTab("sam.sebastian1", "Seb") 
}
```

Comment: Comparison in js is `==`, not `=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers point out that it should be `(domain == face)`, and this **is** an error.

However, **it is not what prevented the script from appearing to work as you expected.**

The main problem is that Chrome userscripts cannot use JS defined in the target page.  You must inject your code into the page, like so:

```
function functionToInject () {
    function myCode () {
        /*--- This is where you put everything you want to do that 
            requires use of the page's javascript.
        */
        var face = "facebook.com"
        var domain = document.domain
        if (domain == face)
        {
            Chat.openTab ("sam.sebastian1", "Seb");
        }
    }
    myCode ();
}

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL) {
    var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";
    if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;

    var targ    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
                || document.body || document.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node ( '(' + functionToInject.toString() + ')()' );
```

---

---

That was the basic answer. **However**, since this is Facebook, things are a bit more complicated.

1. Facebook loads many iFrames, and the script will trigger on many of them.
2. The `Chat` object does not load right away.

To get around these obstacles, we setup a timer, that doesn't try to execute our code until the resource is found.

Like so:

```
function functionToInject () {
    function myCode () {
        /*--- This is where you put everything you want to do that 
            requires use of the page's javascript.
        */
        var face = "facebook.com"
        var domain = document.domain
        if (domain == face)
        {
            Chat.openTab ("sam.sebastian1", "Seb");
        }
    }

    var waitForKeyElements  = setInterval (checkForElement, 500);

    function checkForElement () {
        if (typeof Chat != "undefined" ) {
            clearInterval (waitForKeyElements);
            myCode ();
        }
    }
}

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL) {
    var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";
    if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;

    var targ    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
                || document.body || document.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node ( '(' + functionToInject.toString() + ')()' );
```

Comment: this sounds pretty stupid but what would i have to change in that code if anything at all?

Comment: It's not stupid, since you are using this on Facebook, there are real-life factors to consider... iFrames and the fact that the JS function may not be available right away.  Let me create a Facebook account (¤groan¤) and see if there are any site-specific gotchas here. ... Back in a few...

Comment: the javascript console is giving a syntax error about the <><!

Comment: Sorry about that.  I avoid Chrome AMAP, and forgot it doesn't handle that syntax.  Corrected the answer, and also showed how to handle the practicalities of a ¤cough¤ *complex* site like Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (domain == face)
{
 Chat.openTab("sam.sebastian1", "Seb") 
}
```

not

```
if (domain = face)
{
 Chat.openTab("sam.sebastian1", "Seb") 
}
```