# Get 2 userscripts to interact with each other?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey, interaction

I have two scripts. I put them in the same namespace (the `@namespace` field).

I'd like them to interactive with another.

Specifically I want *script A* to set `RunByDefault` to 123. Have *script B* check if `RunByDefault==123` or not and then have *script A* using a timeout or anything to call a function in *script B*.

How do I do this? I'd hate to merge the scripts.

Comment: I'm suprised this question isn't more upvoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scripts cannot directly interact with each other and [`// @namespace`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40namespace) is just to resolve *script* name conflicts.  (That is, you can have 2 different scripts named "Link Remover", only if they have different namespaces.)

Separate scripts *can* swap information using:

- Cookies -- works same-domain only
- `localStorage` -- works same-domain only
- Sending and receiving values via AJAX to a server that you control -- works cross-domain.

That's it.

Different running instances, *of the same script*, can swap information using `GM_setValue()` and `GM_getValue()`.  This technique has the advantage of being cross-domain, easy, and invisible to the target web page(s).

See [**this working example of cross-tab communication in Tampermonkey**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021508/331508).

---

On Chrome, and only Chrome, you *might* be able to use the non-standard [FileSystem API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to store data on a local file.  But this would probably require the user to click for every transaction -- if it worked at all.

Another option is to write an extension (add-on) to act as a helper and do the file IO. You would interact with it via `postMessage`, usually.

**In practice, I've never encountered a situation were it wasn't easier and cleaner to just merge any scripts that really need to share data.**

---

Also, scripts cannot share code, but they can inject JS into the target page and both access that.

Finally, AFAICT, scripts always run sequentially, not in parallel.  But you can control the execution order from the *Manage User Scripts* panel

Comment: How might i inject a script into the page?

Comment: See the first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935428/why-doesnt-this-userscript-work-on-facebook/6935777#6935777), for example.  Essentially you create a `<script>` node.