# Share a variable between multiple userscripts

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

Here's my problem, I have 2 separate userscripts atm that works on different domains. I have done it this way because apparently I can't request an HTTP url to be parsed if the domain the user currently is using HTTPS.

I have tried using `GM_getValue()` described by the 2nd related link below and that doesn't work. That information saying :

> Scripts can swap information using GM_setValue() and GM_getValue()

seems to be outdated. The other script cannot retrieve the variable that has been set by the other.

using `localstorage` or `cookies` will not work as well because they work in different domains.

I would like to know other ways or workaround before I use the database/server method of saving/retrieving variables

Related/duplicate threads:
[Sharing variables between 2 separate scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949711/sharing-variables-between-2-separate-scripts)
[Get 2 Greasemonkey scripts to interact with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025235/get-2-greasemonkey-scripts-to-interact-with-each-other)

Comment: Updated (or upvoted) the linked answers.  Nothing has changed.  Your smart option is to rethink and merge such scripts.  Your next best option is to AJAX to a server you control.  It is also possible to kludge-up a helper extension to do local (sandboxed) file IO -- with various limitations.