# How to Use Tampermonkey to reload another tab?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to refresh a certain tab when the current tab changes, using `Tampermonkey`.

I am a user of Duolingo, but I am not happy with their new change of the Crown system, and I don't like their algorithm with the 'Practice' button.

So, I use the site *duome.eu* to choose the weakest to review.

Like on this page:
    https://duome.eu/example/progress

The information on this site was based on the progress of the user on 
 duolingo.com.

I click the link on the duome page to open duolingo site to review the skill.
After finished reviewing one skill, I'd like the page of duome.eu to reload to recalculate my progress.

How can I achieve that?

Also I'm open to other ideas, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by:

1. Set your Tampermonkey script to **run on both domains**.
2. **Communicate between script instances** using [`GM_setValue()`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_setValue) and [`GM_addValueChangeListener()`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_addValueChangeListener) and, optionally, [`GM_getValue()`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_getValue).

Say, for example, that you wanted to monitor [this *random* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript), and reload [its timeline page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/521295/timeline) every time you clicked a vote button or the favorite star.

This **complete working Tampermonkey script** does that:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Cross tab, cross domain script communication
// @match    *://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/*
// @match    *://stackoverflow.com/posts/521295/timeline
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_setValue
// @grant    GM_addValueChangeListener
// ==/UserScript==

const xmssionKey = "Last vote-button click event";

//-- Are we on the "interactive" page/site/domain or the "monitoring" one?
if (location.pathname.includes ("questions") ) {
    //-- On the "interactive page/tab...
    //-- Hook into the page's vote and favorite buttons:
    $(".inner-content").on ("click", ".vote a", zEvent => {
        var tmStamp   = new Date ().getTime ();
        var ctMessage = `Button ${zEvent.target.className} clicked - ${tmStamp}`;
        console.log (ctMessage);

        //-- Send message to monitoring tab.
        GM_setValue (xmssionKey, ctMessage);
    } );
}
else {
    //-- On the "monitoring" page/tab...
    //-- Listen for new message:
    GM_addValueChangeListener (
        xmssionKey, (keyName, oldValue, newValue, bRmtTrggrd) => {
            console.log (`Received new event: ${newValue}`);
            //-- User feedback, esp useful with time delay:
            document.title = "Reloading...";
            /*-- Important:
                May need to wait 1 to 300 seconds to allow for
                web-app / database / API delays and/or caching.
                1222 == 1.2 seconds
            */
            setTimeout ( () => {location.reload(); }, 1222);
    } );
}
```

1. Install the script.
2. Open [the timeline page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/521295/timeline).
3. Open [the question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript).
4. Click on one of the vote buttons or on the favorite star.
5. You will see the timeline page reload automatically.

---

Note that for this particular example, both pages are on the same domain (Merely to make it easier for everyone to run the demo script), but **the code/strategy works just as well for cross-domain pages.**

Comment: For others who can't get it working: adding timeStamp or other changing thing to the message is important.

Comment: As far as you know, is there any means to tell TM to share storage across different scripts or does it need to be the same script running on different domains? I can make it work this way, I'd just rather not if it can be avoided.